# How to fix 'getNextDataCell next skipped one cell' error in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

So here's this odd situation where I used this code and the selection was on A4 and after I use the getNextDataCell (NEXT) method it then selected C4 instead of B4????

```
Testsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).setBackground('#000000').setFontColor('#ff0000');
```

And a photo after the execution: https://ibb.co/kBMf8Ff

Here's my full code:

```
function Macro3() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Testsheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Test');
  var data = Testsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if (data[i][0] == 'Harpeth Valley Utilities District'){
      var temp = i + 1;
      Testsheet.getRange('A'+temp).activate();
      Testsheet.getCurrentCell().setBackground('#000000').setFontColor('#ff0000');
      Testsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).setBackground('#000000').setFontColor('#ff0000');
      Testsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).setBackground('#000000').setFontColor('#ff0000');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 3):

#### Issue:

The official document of [`getNextDataCell(direction)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection) says as follows.

> Starting at the cell in the first column and row of the range, returns the next cell in the given direction that is the edge of a contiguous range of cells with data in them or the cell at the edge of the spreadsheet in that direction. This is equivalent to typing Ctrl+[arrow key] in the editor.

From your shared image, the edge is the column of "C". By this, the color of the cell "C4" is changed.

When you want to change the color of "B4" instead of "C4", as a modification, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
Testsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).setBackground('#000000').setFontColor('#ff0000');
Testsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).setBackground('#000000').setFontColor('#ff0000');
```

To:

```
Testsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).setBackground('#000000').setFontColor('#ff0000');
```

#### References:

- [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection)
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.